# Can't resolve Pylint 'too-many-instance-attributes'

Tags: python, pylint

There seems to be something going on behind the scenes with the linter and a few of my classes. I have a few classes with too many (up to 26 in one case) instance attributes. One I was able to fix by grouping together some of the related attributes into new classes. However, this method isn't working for me on the latest class. All the attributes are primitives at the moment, and I can easily break them apart into related groups. The offending class follows:

```
class BigClass():
    """
    This class has too many (16/8) instance attributes!
    """
    a = float(0)
    b = float(0)
    c = float(0)
    d = float(0)
    e = float(0)
    f = float(0)
    g = float(0)
    h = float(0)
    i = float(0)
    j = float(0)
    k = float(0)
    l = float(0)
    m = float(0)
    n = float(0)
    o = float(0)
    p = float(0)
```

I then broke it up into two classes, grouping together appropriate attributes.

```
class SmallClass1():
    """
    This class is smaller, it has 8/8 attributes.
    It is a logical grouping of 8 attributes that were
    previously found in BigClass()
    """
    a = float(0)
    b = float(0)
    c = float(0)
    d = float(0)
    e = float(0)
    f = float(0)
    g = float(0)
    h = float(0)

class SmallClass2():
    """
    This class is smaller, it has 8/8 attributes.
    It is a logical grouping of 8 attributes that were
    previously found in BigClass()
    """
    i = float(0)
    j = float(0)
    k = float(0)
    l = float(0)
    m = float(0)
    n = float(0)
    o = float(0)
    p = float(0)

class NewBigClass():
    """
    This class still has too many (16/8) instance attributes!
    """
    grouping1 = SmallClass1()
    grouping2 = SmallClass2()
```

However, the linter is still claiming that there are too many attributes in the NewBigClass() declaration.
Am I missing something, perhaps the core understanding of what this warning is trying to avoid?
I'm not sure why I was able to solve this for one class, but not all of them. They all follow a similar layout.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which version of `python` and `pylint` are you running?

Comment: `Python 3.7`
`Pylint 2.1.1`
`pylint-django 2.0.2`
`Windows10`

Comment: I think I've figured out what is wrong, but I need to refactor some code before I can be sure. If it turns out to resolve my issues, I will add an answer in case someone else makes the same mistakes as me. Even though I modified the class, I didn't change all the references, so the rest of my code was adding more attributes throughout the project...

Comment: This is a strange error, since your classes have *no instance attributes*

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue.

While refactoring my classes to reduce the number of instance attributes, I ran pylint before completely refactoring that class throughout the entire project. This meant that while I broke up class.a, class.b, etc., I was still assigning class.a somewhere else in the project.

After fixing those references, my pylint warning was fixed.

Thanks to all who contributed.